# deleting bootstrap colorpicker value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

i have a simple text field which has a colorpicker attached to it.
i have added an icon next to the field, which is able to remove the content of the field value (which was generated by the color picker).  code is below.

the strange thing is that *after* i delete the value -  if i click elsewhere on the page, the value comes back! code and simple sample below.

reproduction steps:

1. generate hex code by using the colorpicker.
2. click on the X to delete the field value.
3. click elsewhere in the page body, the value will return.

many thanks

HTML code:

```
  <input type="text" name="x_fontColor" id="x_fontColor" size="30" maxlength="10" value="" class="colorpicker">
  <span class="trigger" data-for="x_fontColor">X </span>
```

JS:

```
$(".colorpicker").colorpicker();            
$(".trigger").click(function(){
   $("#"+$(this).data('for')).val('');              
});
```

FIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/W2Mcy/

Comment: It happens in the [plugin's site](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/) too.They are using `mousedown` event in their calculations [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js).

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/), it seems you can use

```
.colorpicker('setValue', value)
```

I tried it in your fiddle, and it is working but the below sets the `#ff0000` as default color.

```
$(".trigger").on('click', function(){
                $('input').colorpicker('setValue', '').val(''); // clear both value of input and set default color  
            });
```

See this [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Mcy/2/).

Hope you understand.

Comment: @kneidels Trying to figure out.  hope will find it.

Comment: thanks. i thought i was doing something wrong. but maybe its a bug in the script

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but if someone else runs into this issue you can assign 'transparent' as the value.

```
.colorpicker('setValue','transparent');
```

Unfortunately the color picker will display 'transparent' in the field so it's not entirely a null or '' value, but it's close and it should work if you're doing a live update of the color in a preview type of situation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: interesting, thanks. can you give a simple fiddle to see?